# Is it possible to programmatically rebuild a Sitecore HTML cache for a specific range of pages?

Tags: html, caching, sitecore

I've inherited a Sitecore 6.5 project that happens to have a lot of content editors publishing content very frequently.  Each time a publish happens, the HTML cache invalidates.  Typically this is no problem, however, there are a number pages that take a very long time to load.

Overall, those pages need to be rearchitected, however as a temporary solution, I thought I could trigger the HTML cache to rebuild programmatically on item publish for specific pages.  After some research, it seems you can only programmatically clear the cache, but not rebuild.  Is this really the case, or is there something I might be missing?

Answer (score 3):

In the past we have used a few different means of getting HTML cache built depending on version of Sitecore and IIS.  The answer also differs with the network infrastructure used.  There is a (not so elegant) solution of attaching a publish (and publish:remote) event listener and then programmatically sending requests to an array of URLs from the back end will generate HTML cache.  Remember to hit all machines in a load balanced setup

Also, I know you aren't spurring an app pool recycle with a publish, but if you do have a periodic recycle the IIS warm up module (described here: http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2009/10/14/now-available-the-iis-7-5-application-warm-up-module.aspx) is a good option.

Comment: Ahh, that's essentially the same idea I thought of after discovering the lack of rebuild options.  Like you said, it's not so elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Something we have done in the past is to use workflow to stage items that are ready for publish then run scheduled tasks to publish items in the final workflow state only a couple times a day- this will reduce the number of cache rebuilds.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option due to business requirements (content changes many times throughout the day).

Comment: Even if you publish once an hour it would help avoid the constant publishing & rebuilding through out the day. Business requirements are a drag.